# RichFileManager - FlaskFileManager in FileField WTForms

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, file-manager

I'm using RichFileManager
https://github.com/psolom/RichFilemanager https://github.com/stevelittlefish/flaskfilemanager https://pypi.org/project/flaskfilemanager
in my Flask app for uploading/selecting/etc images with CKEditor4. So I have a form with some inputs, one of which is TextAreaField which is used for CKEditor.
I have FileField also, and its opening folder on my pc. Everything is working fine.

I was wondering, is there a way to make that FileField use that FileManager? So I select image from there, not from local file explorer.

Currently if I want to select/use image thats already been used in that FileField I need to select it again on my PC and then app checks if it exists and depending on that uploads it or returns filename.

With flaskfilemanager I could select image that's already been used.

I can't find any solution, maybe someone knows how or has any idea.

Thank you !